# Fiddler: UnGZip faild. The content could not be decompressed

Tags: fiddler

[Click here picture shows the error, thanks!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlBLG.png)

I don't know which session it captured occurs the error, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, this is a limitation in the way that feature works. Please ensure you're on the latest version of Fiddler, and consider disabling the "Decode" option in Fiddler's toolbar; use the manual decoding features available in the Transformer response inspector.